# How to extract positional values separated by delimiter in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a text file like this below (Text). I want to extract these values in the result. How do I do this?

Code I tried:

```
cat Text | cut -d\t -f1| cut -d: -f1,2,3,4
```

Result I want:

```
D8FF8JN1:143:D1XX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:GACXX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1
```

Text:

```
D8FF8JN1:143:D1XX:1:1101:6330:193670       141     *       0       0       *       *       0       0       CACTTCAAAGCCTCCCACCTATCCTACACAGATCCGTTCTAAGTCCAATACAAAGCTACAGTAAAGGTTCATGGGGATCGTCGGACTGTAGAAATCTGA   CCFFFFFHHHHHJJJIHIEIIJIJJJJJGIIIJJJJJJJJJJJGIJJJHHIIJJGHIJGIJHIJJGGGIIGIEHFHFFF<CDDD@=@BC;,;@(4:>C@
D8FF8JN1:143:GACXX:1:1101:6271:193678       77      *       0       0       *       *       0       0       TCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTTCGCCCGCCAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTAGCTTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTGAAAA   CCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJIJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJJIJHHFHFFFFFFEEEEEEDCCDDDDDCDDB?CCCDDDDDDDDCCCCAACDD
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1:1101:6271:193678       141     *       0       0       *       *       0       0       GGCGGGCGAAATGTGCGTTCAAAGATTCGATGATCGTCGGACTGTAGAACTCTGAACGTGTAGATCTCGGTGGTCGCCGTATCATTAAAAAAAAAAAAA   CCFFFFFHFHHHIFHGGHIGIJJGHGHEFEEHHHFDEFCD?BBBCD@CC@CCCCCDC??BCCCADCCCAB<<@5@-9@9<@B<@4@@CCDDBBD#####
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1:1101:6385:193738       77      *       0       0       *       *       0       0       GGAACGGGCTTGGAA
```

Comment: Please add your expected output with your own code attempt.

Comment: Q: How to extract positional values separated by delimiter in shell?  A: From the shell, type [man cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).  We can't tell from your post what "delimiter" you need, But let's say you want the 1st column, delimited by a tab: `cut -f1 -d$'\t' results.txt`

Comment: @New_to_R : Do you mean that you have as input the file _Text_ and want as output the file _Result_? I also don't see any bash script in your question. It is difficult to discuss your program, if you don't post it.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes Result is the expected output. I tried `cat Text | cut -d\t -f1| cut -d: -f1,2,3,4`

Comment: @New_to_R : Add your code to your question, not into a comment. Note that you can **edit** your question. Don't forget to **format your code** properly (indenting by 4 spaces).

Comment: `awk -F: '{for (i=1; i<=4; i++) printf (i==1) ? "%s" : ":%s", $i; print ""}' file`

Comment: `cut -d\t` is a syntax error, it requires a single character and you are passing in a literal backslash and a literal `t`.  But the default delimiter for `cut` is a tab so if that's what you mean, just omit the option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two different `cut` commands, what you want to print is well defined by the colon delimiter and you want the first 4 fields.

```sh
cut -d ':' -f1-4 file
```

```
D8FF8JN1:143:D1XX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:GACXX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1
D8FF8JN1:143:D1D19ACXX:1
```

Note: Just in case you 'd like to use a delimiter like tab with `cut` in a linux shell, use this syntax: `-d $'\t'` to define one character, the tab, or any other character escaped with backslash.